# Use Selenium to download files without URL

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download an audio file from a webpage. I can only listen to the file on the site. I tried copying the URL of the file but turns out there's no URL. The file is embedded in an h5 tag as shown below:

```
<h5 class="mp3-1 pum-trigger" style="cursor: pointer;" audio="audio-8649-20_html5">
Hangup to Qualified Lead - Sample 1
</h5>
```

Can I retrieve the audio file?? If yes, how can I retrieve it?? I've added the link to the site below:
https://reivault.com/salesninjateam/

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an URL. Use the Network tab (F12 or Developer Tools -> Network) to find out what it is.

For example, this is the URL of [Hangup to Qualified Lead - Sample 2](https://reivault.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Existing_to_Qualified_Lead_Stephanie-2.mp3?_=19)

Hence you just need to write the code like this

```
import requests

url = 'https://reivault.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Existing_to_Qualified_Lead_Stephanie-2.mp3?_=19'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('/tmp/file.mp3', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the src of the audio from the audio tag with id as the audio attribute, u can use urllib to download the src:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://reivault.com/salesninjateam/)")


elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(text(),'Hangup to Qualified Lead - Sample 1')]")

id = elem.get_attribute("audio")

audioElem = driver.find_element_by_id(
   id)

src = audioElem.get_attribute("src")

print(src)


urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "a.mp3")

driver.close()
```

You can download all files as :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://reivault.com/salesninjateam")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)
elems = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
    By.XPATH, "//h5[contains(@class,'pum-trigger')]")))


print(elems)
for elem in elems:
    id = elem.get_attribute("audio")
    if id.find("audio") != -1:
        print(id)
        audioElem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.ID, id)))
        src = audioElem.get_attribute("src")
        print(src)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "a.mp3")
        driver.close()
    else:
        pass
```